# ERROR: Failed to > build gem native extension. - Can't install taps gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, heroku

I cannot install the taps gem. I tried running:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev
cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136/ext/readline
ruby extconf.rb
make
sudo make install
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Building native extensions.  This
>   could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing taps:  ERROR: Failed to
>   build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>   ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby
> ```
>
> extconf.rb checking for sqlite3.h...
>   no sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port
>   install sqlite3 +universal' or 'yum
>   install sqlite3-devel' and check your
>   shared library search path (the
>   location where your sqlite3 shared
>   library is located).
>   *** extconf.rb failed ***

Any idea what I did exactly/how to fix?

Comment: I figured it out

running this allowed me to install taps:

    sudo aptitude install libsqlite3-dev
http://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/heroku-taps-and-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the SQLite3 package, with the development headers.  On Ubuntu, this would be:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```